# Reshaping data frame in python as a panel data

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, panel-data

I am importing economic time series from world bank using python with the following code:

```
import wbgapi as wb

countries = ['ALB', 'DZA'] # List of countries
series = ['NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG', 'TX.VAL.MRCH.R3.ZS'] # Economic variables

dt = wb.data.DataFrame(series=series, 
                       economy=countries, 
                       time=range(2013, 2016, 1), 
                       labels=False).reset_index()
dt.head()
```

```
| economy |      series       |    2013   |    2014   |    2015   |
|---------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| ALB     | NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG | 0.288746  |  1.549917 |  0.563991 |
| ALB     | TX.VAL.MRCH.R3.ZS | 0.073716  |  0.057046 |  0.023478 |
| DZA     | NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG | -0.093304 | -0.300580 | -6.455650 |
| DZA     | TX.VAL.MRCH.R3.ZS | 4.452251  |  5.499418 |  5.023353 |
```

my problem is, how to reshape this df to be like this:

```
| economy | year | NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG | TX.VAL.MRCH.R3.ZS |
|---------|------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   ALB   | 2013 |      0.288746     |     0.073716      |
|   ALB   | 2014 |      1.549917     |     0.057046      |
|   ALB   | 2015 |      0.563991     |     0.023478      |
|   DZA   | 2013 |      -0.093304    |     4.452251      |
|   DZA   | 2014 |      -0.300580    |     5.499418      |
|   DZA   | 2015 |      -6.455650    |     5.023353      |
```

Comment: `dt.set_index(['economy', 'series']).rename_axis(columns='year').stack().unstack('series').reset_index()`  or same logic with `melt`+`pivot`